# I am getting android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException "SELECTamountFROMnilanjan_tableWHEREName": syntax error (code 1):

Tags: sqlite

I am getting android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException "SELECTamountFROMnilanjan_tableWHEREName": syntax error (code 1):

```
public Cursor getItemID(String name)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db =this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT" + COL_3 + "FROM" + TABLE_NAME +"WHERE" + COL_2 + " = '" + name + "'" ;
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: SQL queries require spaces. The query cannot all be one word.

Comment: Thanks it really helped

Answer (score 0):

`"SELECTamountFROMnilanjan_tableWHEREName"` from your error message is the result of your concatination to be executed as query.

you need to add spaces between your keywords to create a valid query.:

```
"SELECT " + COL_3 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_2 + " = '" + name + "'" ;
```